# LotusScript Common elements in two Arrays

Tags: arrays, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have two arrays which are not ordered and may be of different lengths, I want to create a new array that contains only the common elements. I need a function like
newArray = commonElements(Array1, Array2) in LotusScript.

Looked around to see if there was a code example but could not find one. Have been sort of able to create this but with a lot more looping than I think should be necessary.

can you point me to a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function returns the common elements of both arrays:

```
Function commonElements(array1 As Variant, array2 As Variant) As Variant
    Dim newArray() As Variant 
    Dim i As Integer 
    i=0 
    ForAll v In array1
        If ArrayGetIndex(array2, v, 0) >= 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve newArray(i) 
            newArray(i) = v 
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End ForAll 
    commonElements = newArray 
End Function
```

Comment: One small change 
If ArrayGetIndex(array2, v, 0) => 0 Then
if the zeroth element is contained in both arrays then it gets missed , other than that it works like a charm.
Thanks

Comment: ArrayGetIndex unfortunately is different from Instr. Instr returns "0" if the string is not found. ArrayGetIndex returns NULL. The right check would be: `If Not IsNull( ArrayGetIndex( array2, v, 0) then`

Answer (score 1):

This works for string arrays, I didn't test with numbers:

```
FullTrim(ArrayReplace(src1, ArrayReplace(src1, src2, Null), Null))
```

Comment: Works with numbers too. Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have used Knut's solution but need it to be able to compare two arrays of unknown length. So modified the ForAll must cycle through the longer of the two arrays:

```
Function commonElements(array1 As Variant, array2 As Variant) As Variant
    Dim newArray() As Variant 
    Dim bigArray As Variant
    Dim smallArray As Variant
    If (UBound(Array1) => UBound(Array2)) Then
        bigArray = array1
        smallArray = array2
    Else
        bigArray = array2
        smallarray = array1
    End If
    Dim i As Integer 
    i=0 
    ForAll v In bigArray
        If ArrayGetIndex(smallArray, v, 0) >= 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve newArray(i) 
            newArray(i) = v 
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End ForAll 
    commonElements = newArray 
End Function
```

Comment: You don't need to do it as you are interested in common elements only. You could use it as an optimization but then you would iterate over smallArray. I'd go with @D.Bugger solution though. Performance should be similar but code is way shorter...